# Open Source Java Based Blog Software

Tags: java, open-source, blogging

I am looking for an open source java blogging software that is easy to use and customise.

I am looking a blog application that (preferably) has the following features:

1. Enable me to tag my post with multiple tags.
2. Can be run under apache tomcat 6.0
3. Spring MVC based
4. Filters comments that has spam

Does anyone has a suggestion ?

Comment: See sister site: [*Personal blog hosting, based on Java Servlet technology*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/53933/1255).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pebble](http://pebble.sourceforge.net/) seems to be what you need:

> Pebble is a lightweight, open source,
>   Java EE blogging tool. It's small,
>   fast and feature-rich with unrivalled
>   ease of installation and use. Blog
>   content is stored as XML files on disk
>   and served up dynamically, so there's
>   no need to install a database.

Content

```
* Posting and management of content through your web browser, including rich text editor support.
* Blogger and MetaWeblog API interface included for posting content via compatible tools.
* Categorisation of content into multiple hierarchical categories.
* Tagging of content and a generation of a tagcloud.
* RSS enclosures for distributing files or podcasting.
* Pinging websites via XML-RPC when new blog entries are added.
* Link to your favorite social bookmarking site
```

Reader responses

```
* Reader responses, in the form of threaded comments and MovableType TrackBacks.
* E-mail notifications when new responses are received.
* Pluggable moderation, spam detection and CAPTCHA support.
* Bulk response management features to approve/reject/remove comments and TrackBacks.
```

Pebble uses the following technologies

- Java
- JavaServer Pages
- JSP Standard Tag Library
- Java Servlets
- Acegi Security System for Spring
- Spring
- Apache Lucene
- Jakarta Commons
- Apache XML-RPC
- Radeox

Comment: Pebble is no longer maintained.